# Rails3: Find method not working with fixtures in test environment

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, fixtures

The Rails Guide says, "Fixtures can also transform themselves into the form of the original class. Thus, you can get at the methods only available to that class," and gives the example,

```
# using the find method, we grab the "real" david as a User 
david = users(:david).find
```

My fixtures are working ok, but when I try

```
    memb = members(:one).find
```

I get an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `find'. What am I doing wrong?

(Rails Guide reference: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures)

Comment: Ever get to the bottom of this? I am running up against the same problem.

Comment: Same here. Seems to be with only specific fixtures.

Comment: Apparently the answer is "don't use fixtures" https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails

Comment: Why do you need to call find?  When I use fixtures, memb = members(:one) should be enough to assign memb to the variable one from the members.yml file.

Comment: typeoneerror & user564761 ... sorry, this was so long ago and I switched from fixtures to FactoryGirl, so I don't even remember what the issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide is fixed now, and find is not necessary anymore because now `users(:david)` is the ActiveRecord object.